Error when trying to debug "Apex language server could not provide information about valid breakpoints"
Every now and then when I want to start a debug sessions from a log file, I receive the following error:
Apex language server could not provide information about valid breakpoints

I have a workaround, and that is to remove the apex.db file from path:
.\.sfdx\tools\248.
This is of course very annoying, since I first have to close VS Code before I'm able to remove the file.
Does anyone have an idea about the origin of this error and how to properly solve it? Many thanks!

I recommend opening an issue on the github for the project
https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues

This solution worked for me. You have to clear the Apex Language Server’s indexing. To do it :
delete the PROJECT_DIR/.sfdx/tools/ directory and restart VS Code.
More details here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/language-server#reset-apex-indexing
